# Bluemix Blockchain Chaincode demo producing "Undefined" error

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I created a Blockchain service in Bluemix and tested the web-based demo of chaincode (the one with Example02, Marbles, and Commercial Paper).

I clicked the Deployed button for Example02 and it is successful.  However, when I click the "Query A" button, it gave an "undefined" error.

Do I need to do additional steps before clicking the "Query A" button?

Below is the console output:

```
Registering enrollID dashboarduser_type1_e367e87de4
  Success - registering enrollID

Deploying chaincode https://github.com/masterDev1985/hyperledger_chaincode/chaincode_example02
  Success - deployment (wait for the cc to start up)...

  done
Querying function - query ["a"]
  Error - undefined

Querying function - query ["a"]
  Error - query
```

Comment: Can you provide the link for the Example02 demo you are using?  I only see marbles, commercial paper, and car lease demos mentioned on the bluemix blockchain sample apps page.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are missing a step.  When you deployed the chaincode you only submitted the code that powers the demo app "Marbles".  There is no marble yet. Before you can query the marble you should create one.  Click the "Create Marble" button. Then do the query, and all should be well.